# What is the correct way to transliterate O'Neil or a similar name?

Tags: транслитерация

Not sure how to correctly write this - as one word, separate?  Do I retain the apostrophe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually the apostrophe in personal names retains, so we have in translation [Юджин О'Нил](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%E2%80%99%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BB,_%D0%AE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD), [Шакил О'Нил](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%E2%80%99%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BB,_%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BB) and actually a lot of other [`О'Нил`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%E2%80%99%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BB)s. The same about Жанна Д'Арк (or д'Арк) or Габриеле Д’Аннунцио (or д’Аннунцио) etc.

This is what you'll see in newspapers and books. In official documents it could be more tricky though. I won't be surprised that there are no regulations about this particular case so say some O'Neil will decide to become a Russian citizen he can be written just as О-Нил or О`Нил. Bureaucracy is a bureaucracy so I can imagine some stubborn official (check out for instance, [this post](http://www.virtualireland.ru/showthread.php?t=51840)) - but this has nothing to do with Russian language, so let it be )

Comment: Just a fun fact: I've seen the name of the mathematician d'Alembert pretty many times in the Russian texts and it's always transliterated as Даламбер. Otherwise, I fully agree (for what my poor Russian skills are worth :—)).

Comment: @Ramillies sure, historical spellings can go against any rules. Few Japanese words, city names among them, are not spelled according to Polivanov's system for the latter did not exist when they came in use.

Comment: @bipil: Absolutely. That just came to my mind when I read the question, that's all.